# How to get only specific input from Laravel request?

Tags: laravel-5

I have input request from controller as below code.

```
   public function CreateSave(Request $request){
       return $request;
   }
```

Below are printed inputs request.

```
 {
    _token: "jf9SQUP48wrPz9LBT8ItZ76UHOc4lD6ot3HrF0bB",
    hn: null,
    prefix: "1",
    name: john,
    lastname: doe,
    room: "1",
    custom_1154: "100",
    custom_51741: "99660"
 }
```

But, I would like to get only input contain specific string '`custom_`'. So result should be like this.

```
 {
    custom_1154: "100",
    custom_51741: "99660"
 }
```

I may use foreach loop but I'm not sure other smart way capable. Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried something, see this is helping you.

```
$collection =  collect($request->all())->reject(function($item, $key){
       if (strpos($key,'custom_') !== false) {
           return false;
       } else {
           return true;
       }
   })->toArray();
```